# Unmatched nodes in two graphs using networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I have two graphs. And i want to know what is the node that make the two graphs "non morphic" using networkx.

`nx.is_isomorphic(G1, G2)` will check if two graph ismorphic and return **True** or **False**.

Comment: Graph isomorphism is a hard problem, and identifying the isomorphic subgraphs is *even worse* because you have to determine the isomorphism between (potentially) all 2^m subgraphs of G1 and all 2^n subgraphs of G2.

Comment: @aryamccarthy I dived into the netwrokx library scripts ans found it iterative process.
I found the best solution is break once the ismorphism is broken and return the node or edge that has not correspond!